# Get the full path of the only file in a directory

Tags: bash

I have a directory with a single file. The name of the file is randomized, but the extension is fixed.

```
myDirectory
|----file12321.txt
```

Is there a one-line way to extract the full path of that file?

```
MY_FILE=myDirectory/*.txt
```

Current output:

```
/home/me/myDirectory/*.txt
```

Expected:

```
/home/me/myDirectory/file12321.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readlink` to get canonized path.

```
MY_FILE=$(readlink -f myDirectory/*.txt)
```

If you want only `myDirectory/file12321.txt` part you could run a command that will let shell expand `*`, like:

```
MY_FILE=$(printf "%s\n" myDirectory/*.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's certain that there is exactly one file, you can just use an array:

```
MY_FILE=( /home/me/myDirectory/*.txt )
```

Filename expansion takes place inside an array definition but not when setting the value of a normal variable. And you can just use the array like a normal variable, as that will provide the value of the first element:

```
$ foo=(1 2 3)
$ echo "$foo"
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MY_FILE=$(pwd)/$(ls myDirectory/*.txt)
# $MYFILE == /home/me/myDirectory/file12321.txt
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes